# UIImageView wait for animation complete

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

I'm trying to execute 2 different animations, after the first complete, using `isAnimating`.

but, I see only the first animation...

```
if anims[0] == 1{
    startAnimation(image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "first"))
}
if anims[1] == 2{
    while myView.isAnimating {
        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.05))
    }
}
startAnimation(image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "second") , time : Int)
```

spriteSheet returns UIImage array after cropping..

```
func startAnimation(image : UIImage , time : Int){
   myView.animationImages = image.spriteSheet(cols: 19, rows: 1)
    myView.animationDuration = 1
    myView.animationRepeatCount = time
    myView.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always chain animations like

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        //do your animation here
    }) { (state) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            //do your second animation
        })
    }
```

If you are using CABasicAnimations then you can use beginTime and duration to chain them up :)

```
    var totalDuration = 0
    let baseicAnim1 = CABasicAnimation()
    baseicAnim1.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    totalDuration += 10
    baseicAnim1.duration = CFTimeInterval(totalDuration)

    let basicAnim2 = CABasicAnimation()
    basicAnim2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + CFTimeInterval(totalDuration)
    totalDuration += 10
    basicAnim2.duration = CFTimeInterval(totalDuration)
```

**EDIT**

Using while loop to keep checking if animation has completed its execution or not is never a suggested approach

**EDIT :**

Try this,

```
func startAnimation(image : UIImage , time : Int,completionBlock : (()->())?){
    let animationDuration = 1
    myView.animationImages = image.spriteSheet(cols: 19, rows: 1)
    myView.animationDuration = animationDuration
    myView.animationRepeatCount = time
    myView.startAnimating()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animationDuration, execute: {
        if let block = completionBlock {
            block()
        }
    })
}
```

Now your startAnimation function takes completion block as its parameter and executes the completion block after animationDuration. So you can get to know when animation ends :)

to chain simply call

```
self.startAnimation(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "first"), time: 1) { 
            self.startAnimation(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "second"), time: 1, completionBlock: nil)
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i'm using `UIImageView`, not `UIView`. my method `startAnimation()` uses animationImages to loop through

Comment: @marry-g : Show ur code in startAnimation() what exactly is that doing ?

Comment: Added, please check now

Comment: The point is, the two animations not necessarily come one after the other.                i have condition, `if anims[0] == 1{
    startAnimation...
}
if anims[1] == 2{
   ...
}`   they are not necessarily come together.. also `.now() + animationDuration` Type of expression is ambiguous without more context